# How to move only purchased music from iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, itunes

I have multiple Macs registered to my iTunes account.  If I plug my iPhone in to any Mac other than the one I usually sync with it, I have the option to transfer purchased items from my iPhone to the connected Mac.  This works great for moving music I purchase on my iMac to my MacBook.  However, every time I hit "transfer purchases," it also tries to transfer applications.  I have no reason to puts apps on my MacBook, and don't see any reason to waste the disk space.  Is there any way to tell iTunes to only transfer purchased *music* off the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are over a year later.  I still haven't figured out how to do it, and it doesn't look like anyone else has either, so I'm going to assume you can't.  Luckily, this has now been rendered mostly irrelevant by iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this :

- The first time iTunes ask to transfer
  purchases, say No
- In the App Tab of your iPhone in iTunes, uncheck the top box : "**Sync Apps**"
- On the bottom of Application Tab, you'll find another box you can try to disable : "**Automatically sync new apps**"
- Try a new sync

Comment: I'm not looking to sync, though.  My iPhone already syncs with my iMac, and I'm trying to transfer the purchases to my MacBook Pro using the "Transfer Purchases" function.  This completely ignores sync settings and just copies everything from my iPhone.  I've got several gigs of apps, and copying them to my MBP is just a waste of time and space.

Comment: What about Big Sur and beyond?  Where iTunes is gonzo?